# Trying to connect from a docker container to docker host running Django in development mode gets connection refused

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm running a django development server in my Debian GNU/Linux host machine with `python manage.py runserver`.

After running a Debian docker container with

`$ docker run -it --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway debian bash`

I expected I could make a curl in http://localhost:8000 with

`curl http://host.docker.internal:8000`

but I get

`Failed to connect to host.docker.internal port 8000: Connection refused`

Is it something related to running Django with `python manage.py runserver`?

Comment: I am not hugely familiar with this but it looks like all your doing is adding the gateway address to the hosts file, but thats not the ip address of the host machine.

Comment: If the dev server is only listening on the 127.0.0.1 localhost interface, it may not be reachable from containers, which call from a different network interface.

Comment: That's right @DavidMaze. It's necessary to run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` for example, and the container will be able to access the host. Thank you.